# How to export Telerik Data into .csv file in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik-reporting

I have develop a small application in asp.net and i have genarate Telerik reports to get data,in aspx i took the telerik report viewer and when i run and click the button it genarate "**.pdf**" file it's fine.But,i want generate the .csv file

**Here is My code(c#)**

```
    protected void btndayreport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Clients client = new Clients();
        ScheduleReport dayreport = new ScheduleReport();
        dayreport.date = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
        RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", dayreport, null);
        string reports = System.DateTime.Now + "DayReport.pdf";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/Reports/") + reports, FileMode.Create);
        // FileStream fs = new FileStream("BeforeMergeReport.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        // ReadPdfFile();
    }
```

please help me ,i have try replace .csv insted of .pdf in RenderingResult it showing error is there any other solution? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

1. reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", dayreport, null) to reportProcessor.RenderReport("CSV", dayreport, null)
2. System.DateTime.Now + "DayReport.pdf" to System.DateTime.Now + "DayReport.csv"

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response it is working,But header names not displaying it just show Textbox names .